# Should I make functions using $scope or directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I made some tests in angular to display an `alert` and both worked just fine.

This example:

```
<a href="" test>Foo</a>
```

js (outside controller):

```
myApp.directive('test', function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('click', function(){
            alert('Foo');
        });
    }
});
```

and this example:

```
<a href="" ng-click="test()">Foo</a>
```

js (inside controller):

```
$scope.test = function(){
    alert('Foo');
}
```

Like I said, both worked. But, which one is correct for manipulating DOM and event handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that you should use directives when you want to make it a component for reuse for example.

That's okay to use `ng-click` for a simple alert, but imagine when more DOM manipulation is needed. In this case a directive is a better solution.

This is a good read about AngularJS directives: [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Directive](https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/).

Comment: In this case, if I want to create element `onclick`, push it inside existing array and re use it for querying, I should use `directive`, right?

Comment: That's a good use for a directive. You can use a isolated scope to keep the directive re-usable and also easier to test.